# t-sql unicode function returns 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unicode

I have string saved on nvarchar(100) column named 
**address**.

```
SELECT UNICODE(address) FROM clients
```

Here is the result set

> ---
>
> 0

What is a symbol it is? How I can find index of this symbol in another locations of my string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in BOL

> Returns the integer value, as defined by the Unicode standard, for the
>   first character of the input expression.

So you also can display the first symbol as binary to examine it

```
SELECT UNICODE(address), CAST(SUBSTRING(address, 1, 1) as varbinary(2)) FROM clients
```

The following also return 0

```
SELECT UNICODE(CAST(0x00 AS NVARCHAR))
SELECT UNICODE(NCHAR(0))
```

**So** - the simplest answer - it is a NCHAR(0) - character

**To find the `NCHAR(0)` in string see the following example:**

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(100) = N'John'+NCHAR(0)+N'Smith'
SELECT CHARINDEX(NCHAR(0) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, @str)
```

Comment: SELECT charindex(clients.address, nchar(0)) from clients where charindex(clients.address, nchar(0))>0  it returns : 0 rows affected. How to find index of nchar(0)?

Comment: you're right about: it is a NCHAR(0) -character. But I can't find it index in string.

Comment: Updated the answer for searching 0 values

Comment: And you used wrong sequence of parameters in CHARINDEX. 1st parameter is WHAT you want to find, and second - IN WHAT

Comment: Thanks. charindex - it's typical mistace. collate helps me there.